# Sonar 3.6.1 : Manual metrics and treemap components

Tags: sonarqube

I have a problem with SonarQube 3.5.1 / 3.6 / 3.6.1.

I use web API to inject manual metrics values for a project like this :
`curl -u user:password -d "resource=<project>&metric=<key of metric>&val=<value>" http://localhost:8081/sonar/api/manual_measures`
More over, I use sonar-runner (with a .properties file) to run analysis after injected these values.

One of these metrics is a percentage and this metric is declared as a Percent Unit value in Sonar (in Settings => Manual Metrics menu).
I have a project with components and each project and components have this metric value injected and I can see it in Sonar.

When I want to show this metric as a color metric in a "treemap of components" widget, all the treemap is grey (as if values are not defined).

But if I put mouse on the name of component in treemap, I see the color metric value as a percentage value like this :
    myComponent - ncloc: 800 - myMetric: 84,0%

Moreover, scale metric color does not appear in treemap title (after `Size ncloc Color <my metric>`).

Colors and scale appear if I choose an other metric for color (not a manual metric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem.

In metrics table in database, i realized that my manuals metrics for color treemap don't have worst_value and best_value (value was NULL).

```
select * from metrics where name like 'sp_violations_density';
```

Result :

```
+-----+-----------------------+------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------------+---------+--------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------+
| id  | name                  | description      | direction | domain | short_name                    | qualitative | val_type | user_managed | enabled | origin | worst_value            | best_value               | optimized_best_value | hidden | delete_historical_data |
+-----+-----------------------+------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------------+---------+--------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------+
| 161 | sp_violations_density | Rules compliance |         0 | Issues | SyncPerl Compliance Rules (%) |           1 | PERCENT  |            1 |       1 | GUI    |                   NULL |                     NULL |                 NULL |   NULL |                   NULL |
+-----+-----------------------+------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------+----------+--------------+---------+--------+------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+--------+------------------------+
```

So i set them with 0 and 100.

```
update metrics set worst_value='0' where name LIKE 'sp_violations_density';
update metrics set best_value='100' where name LIKE 'sp_violations_density';
```

Need a Tomcat restart, and then it works.

Treemap has colors now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact feeding a manual metric is a two steps mechanim:

- Define the value of this manual metric as you did by calling for instance the 'manual_measures' web service
- Launch a Sonar analysis on this project to 'associate' this manual measure to the latest quality snapshot of this project

Then you should be able to use this manual metric in a treemap.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I do a Sonar analysis with sonar-runner and I can see my manual metrics values in Sonar.

The problem is only with treemap color. More over, I can see manual metric values in the treemap too (ex : myComponent - ncloc: 800 - myMetric: 84,0%)... but colors not appear.